# Converting footnotemarks to endnotes

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

I am trying to convert all footnotes and footnotemarks in a large document to endnotes. While the footnotes can be readily converted using `\let\footnote=\endnote`, I am not able to convert footnotemarks to endnotemarks. I am using footnotemarks within footnotes to circumvent LaTeX restrictions on nested footnotes.

Here is an example showing proper conversion of footnotes, but not footnotemarks, to endnotes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\begin{document}
Here is a footnote%
\footnote{That contains two nested footnotes\footnotemark\footnotemark.}.%
\footnotetext{The nested footnote is not automatically converted to an endnote.}
\footnotetext{Likewise.}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you only have a single `\footnotemark`s inside `\footnotes`, then the following should work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes
\let\footnote\endnote
\def\footnotetext{\endnotetext[\number\numexpr\value{endnote}+1]}
\let\footnotemark\endnotemark
\begin{document}
Here is a footnote%
\footnote{That contains a nested footnote\footnotemark.}.%
\footnotetext{The nested footnote is not automatically converted to an endnote.}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Werner. Unfortunately, I also have footnotes that contain multiple footnotemarks.